# Creating a NSD/Bonjour Discoverable service C# without downloading Bonjour

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, service-discovery

I need to create an NSD/Bonjour discoverable service using c#. I have looked into Mono.Zeroconf which works perfectly, but requires Bonjour to be installed, which doesn't work in our situation. Is there any way to do this without installing Bonjour.

note: I am using Xamarin to build my mobile app

Comment: Are you trying to write a C# based bonjour service that is discoverable by iOS/android devices or is that service intended to run on the mobile devices? i.e. Are you trying to reproduce mDNSResponder in C#?

Comment: The service is going to run on a PC, the iOS/Android device has to discover it

Comment: So I assuming that you do not want to go through the Bonjour license agreement to include Apple's installer in your install? The mDNSReponder is opened under Apache 2.0, so you could always use it as a reference and rewrite a C# DNS service (or just use their C source)....